# How do you set an Burst ID using exiftools on MacOS?

Tags: applescript, bash, photos.app, camera, exif

To mark pictures as **burst** in Apple Photos.app a random BurstUUID (same one for all bursts) is required.

By trying to set an UUID with zsh: `exiftool -BurstUUID='A4862FFE-5491-4F15-9AC0-0881859A0802' sample.jpg` it returns

```
0 image files updated
1 image files unchanged
```

Does anyone know why that's the case?
Would be very happy for getting an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## MakerNotes

To add `BurstUUID` for non-iPhone taken photos, you need to copy in `MakerNotes` from an iPhone created image. See [Re: Help with MakerApple metadata](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,6387.msg35855.html?PHPSESSID=3dachimlnlas4itv35q09sjv21#msg35855) for a related discussion and example:

```
exiftool -v -overwrite_original -m -P "-burstuuid=$UUID" -tagsfromfile IMG_0178.jpg G0232134.JPG
```

Phil Harvey, the creator of [`ExifTool`](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), says this [about MakerNotes in relation to BurstUUID](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,6387.msg35863.html#msg35863):

> No.  Makernote tags may not be created individually. They may only be changed if they already exist.  The only way to create them is to copy the entire makernotes as a block.  I suggest maybe creating a user-defined XMP tag instead, and writing this to your GoPro images.

Comment: Is there a way not copy Exif Data like camera model, recording date, aperture, lens information, GPS, ... because in the solution above EXIF data is replaced by the iPhone data.

Comment: @user234837 consider [asking a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to see if this is possible and how to achieve it on your Mac.